# Magento Testing SOAP API's using EcomDev_PHPUnit

Tags: magento-1, soap-api-v2, ecomdev-phpunit

We just started working on a Magento project where there is a need for some complicated changes to the **Magento SOAP API**.

Since we never properly worked with unit tests, this looked like a good case to use unit testing for once. Since these API calls need to be really good tested and very stable.

Now, I heard a lot of great things about the **EcomDev_PHPUnit** extension so after reading a lots of material about it, I installed it and tried to get it working.

But now we run into trouble when performing a SOAP call during those tests. It looks like when you perform a SOAP call using the test `base_url`, defined in the `local.xml.phpunit` file, Magento redirects us to the normal `base_url`. So I'm guessing when the SOAP call comes in, it is probably using the normal database and not the test database. Which makes sense, since this is a new process which bootstraps Magento again through the webserver, so Magento isn't aware it should be running in a test context.

Has anyone got experience with testing SOAP calls using the **EcomDev_PHPUnit** extension? Or does anyone have an idea how to make this work?
It would be very handy for us, since we can use all the great features of this extension, especially the fixtures and the test database.

Thanks!